# How do I programmatically know if Trace32 booting has completed?

Tags: jtag, trace32, lauterbach

We are using Trace32 in our automation environment. I am trying to programmatically control Trace32 and I am able to do it successfully with T32api dlls.

After launching the trace32.exe programmatically (C#/Python 3.7), I wait for 30seconds before communicating with the trace32. During this time, the trace32 finishes booting and ready for remote communication. Is there a way to avoid this hard-coded 30seconds delay by programmatically finding out if the booting is complete?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to connect with function T32_Attach() and repeat until it succeeds.